# exporting table in to a drive from Google earth engine returns blank rows

Tags: export, csv, google-earth-engine

I am trying to find the mean precipitation of a watershed. When I print the feature collection *BasinMean*, I can see the mean precipitation in the console. A lot of them are zeros but the first two rows have non-zero precipitation.

When I export the table in to a drive, I expect a CSV file which is a timeseries with 3 columns - Station, date(timestamp) and mean precipitation. However, with the below code, the generated CSV has empty cells for mean precipitation. Any idea why the export function does not work?

Link to the workspace : https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/7f21f81224e88bed21e2db64fb7fda30

```js
// Filter the image colelction for a certain timeframe
var filtered = Chirps_daily.filterDate('1981-01-01', '2016-12-31');

// Display the basin
Map.addLayer(Basin,{color:"#008080"},"Basin");
print(Basin,"Basin");

// Load the first image of the collection
var Chirps_first = ee.Image(filtered.first());
print(Chirps_first,'Chirps_first');

// Load the scale of the chirps image
var Chirp_scale = Chirps_first.projection().nominalScale();


var BasinMean = Basin.map(function(f) {
    return filtered.map(function(i) {
       var mean = i.reduceRegion({
       geometry: f.geometry(),
       reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    });
    return f.setMulti(mean).set({date: i.date()})
  })
})

// flatten
BasinMean = BasinMean.flatten()
print(BasinMean.limit(20))

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:BasinMean.limit(20),
  folder: "Google EE results",
  selectors:(["Station","date","precipitation"]),
  });
```

Comment: I ran the code provided in the link above, and nothing showed up in my Google Drive. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was suggested a work around for this issue by Jillian Deines in Google Engine developers forum.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers

Quoting Jillian Deines: "I'm not entirely sure why your method doesn't export correctly, since as you note the precip values are there when you print, but my guess has something to do with the way the 'precipitation' value is stored, since that column doesn't export at all if you omit the "selectors" specification in your Export.table.toDrive()

I switched up the code a bit to an approach I often use (using the plural reduceRegions() regardless of the number of features in your collection), and it exports correctly here:
https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/1e2fd2a8dff34099f4bffb25906c0d94

The outer map here is over the collection, vs over the FeatureCollection in your example. Perhaps not a satisfying answer, but it works!"

Code here
https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/1e2fd2a8dff34099f4bffb25906c0d94

```js
var BasinMean = filtered.map(function(img) {
  return img.reduceRegions({
      collection: Basin,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: Chirp_scale
    }).map(function(f){
        return f.set('date', img.date());
    });
}).flatten()
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept this as the correct answer by using the grey/green tick mark to the left.